# Set an XJC javaType adapter in external binding file

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, adapter, xjc

I've an XSD file containing this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://example.org/">

<xsd:complexType name="Certificate">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="certificate" type="xsd:base64Binary">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <xjc:javaType name="java.security.cert.X509Certificate" adapter="adapters.X509CertificateAdapter" />
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>

<xsd:complexType name="User">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="certificate" type="xsd:base64Binary">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <xjc:javaType name="java.security.cert.X509Certificate" adapter="adapters.X509CertificateAdapter" />
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Server">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="document" type="xsd:base64Binary" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I would like to export xjc javaType adapter to an external .xjb file. In this file, I would like to set this adapter for all `certificate` elements with `xsd:base64Binary` type but not for `document` element in `Server` complex type which also has `xsd:base64Binary` type.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your xsd in

```
<xsd:complexType name="Certificate">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="certificate" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="User">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="certificate" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Server">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="document" type="xsd:base64Binary" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and add this binding configuration

```
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:namespace="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/namespace-prefix">
    <bindings schemaLocation="yourXSD.xsd">

            <bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='Certificate']//xsd:sequence//xsd:element[@name='certificate']">
                <xjc:javaType name="java.security.cert.X509Certificate" adapter="adapters.X509CertificateAdapter" />
            </bindings>
            <bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='User']//xsd:sequence//xsd:element[@name='certificate']">
                <xjc:javaType name="java.security.cert.X509Certificate" adapter="adapters.X509CertificateAdapter" />
            </bindings>

    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Yes it's pretty much what I expected as solution, node by node. But is it possible to put it in `globalBindings` to avoid repeating it every time I will add a new `certificate` element ?

Comment: Yes it is using 

<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
 xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net">

  <globalBindings>
  <xjc:javaType xmlType="xsd:base64Binary" name="java.security.cert.X509Certificate" adapter="adapters.X509CertificateAdapter" />
  </globalBindings>
  
</bindings>

Comment: But in this case all `xsd:base64Binary` will use the adapter, even the element `document` in complex type `Server`, which I don't want in this case.

Comment: yes ... global binding is for each xmlType, i think that in your case is better the first solution.