# JAXB marshalling CDATA with Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, cdata, maven-jaxb2-plugin

This is my general problem: I want everything to be **automated** as much as it can be.

This is my specific problem: I want to **marshal/unmarshal CDATA**. I know that I can specify my own adapter as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193944/jaxb-marshalling-unmarshalling-with-cdata). For building process I use Maven and its **maven-jaxb2-plugin**. Is there some option how to annotate elements in `.xsd` so they will be automatically annotated by my custom adapter? I really don't want to manually change those after each build.

Any other ways how to solve my problem are more than welcome. :)

**EDIT:** I've ran to a subproblem and it is described there: [JAXB binding - "unable to honor this conversion customization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183594/jaxb-binding-unable-to-honor-this-conversion-customization).

Comment: If you have problem about configuration, add some example in order to help you better :) maybe my answer does not complete.

Comment: The term "CDATA" means "unparsed character data" and is used to denote a specific representation technique for XML element content: "A CDATA section starts with "<![CDATA[" and ends with "]]>" (w3schools.com)

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: @Xstian - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183594/jaxb-binding-unable-to-honor-this-conversion-customization#comment39356241_25183594

Answer (score 1):

try this configuration

```
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:namespace="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/namespace-prefix">
    <bindings schemaLocation="yourXSD.xsd">

            <bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='Certificate']//xsd:sequence//xsd:element[@name='certificate']">
                <xjc:javaType name="java.security.cert.X509Certificate" adapter="adapters.X509CertificateAdapter" />
            </bindings>
            <bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='User']//xsd:sequence//xsd:element[@name='certificate']">
                <xjc:javaType name="java.security.cert.X509Certificate" adapter="adapters.X509CertificateAdapter" />
            </bindings>

    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

i solved this issue on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952399/set-an-xjc-javatype-adapter-in-external-binding-file/24953369#24953369)

this configuration work fine if is an xmltype like xs:string, xs:date, etc.

Try [this](http://adventuresintechology.blogspot.it/2012/04/binding-custom-xmljavatypeadapter-to.html) configuration to solve your problem, using XmlJavaTypeAdapter.

Comment: Thank you very much Xstian! It looks that it will do the thing, but I still have a big problem. In my schema, I've declared my own complexType. When I want to bind it, plugin tells me that `...undefined simple type...`

Comment: Can you add some configuration or sample? , in order to help you better :)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my comment just after I wrote it to provide source but it somehow didn't save. :)

[article-content.xsd](http://pastebin.com/8SUKnDG8), 
[bindings.xsd](http://pastebin.com/Txpzaqty)

Comment: and as a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183594/jaxb-binding-unable-to-honor-this-conversion-customization