# Unable to honor customizations JAX

Tags: java, xml, xjc

I have looked at this link but couldn't derive a solution to my problem:[JAXB binding - "unable to honor this conversion customization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183594/jaxb-binding-unable-to-honor-this-conversion-customization)

I have this XML

```
<xs:simpleType name="auditory_stimuli">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Which I customized using this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="auditory_stimuli">
<xs:restriction base="xs:boolean">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:javaType name="java.lang.Boolean"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:restriction>
```

However, when I run xjc, I get this exception

```
Specified javaType customization is not used.
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`<xs:annotation>` and the remainder of the binding definition should be inside the `<xs:simpleType>` definition, not inside `<xs:restriction>`.

Try this..

```
<xs:simpleType name="auditory_stimuli">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:javaType name="java.lang.Boolean"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

For something similar, see the following..
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/custom.html#bnbch