# Is there a way to create an additional ObjectFactory-methode that returns JAXBElemen<C>

Tags: binding, jaxb, objectfactory

I have one jaxb-created Class, that is (logically) not annotated with `@XMLRootElement`, because it's a child-node. In one special case, I would like to (un)marshall this single node by using an `JAXBElement`-Wrapper.

With `<jxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="true" />` one can force jaxb to create ObjectFactory-methods that return `JAXBElement`'s.

I would like jaxb not to create all methods that way, but to create that on additional method.

PS: I use ant/xjc to create that classes. That binding is from a binding-file used by xjc.

Comment: How you generated your classes? jaxb2-maven-plugin?

Comment: Sry, I added that information (ant/xjc with bindingfile)

Comment: Try to add <xjc:simple /> in your global binding see [here](https://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#simple) in order to add @XmlRootElement on each class generates. In this way should be generate a correct ObjectFactory.

Comment: `<xjc:simple />` should be inserted in the xsd, right?  In my actual case, xsd is under my control, but what, if not?

Comment: You can externalize the binding in another file .. see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24953369/3364187)

Comment: Added `<jxb:globalBindings><xjc:simple /></jxb:globalBindings>` to my bindingsfile, what didn't help (beside differences in the generated lists).  I think, I will go with an custom wrapper-class of my own ;-)

Comment: Maybe you need this method: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal(javax.xml.transform.Source, java.lang.Class)