# Unsupported binding namespace ""

Tags: xml, maven, jaxb, xsd, hyperjaxb

I have a schema for which `JAXB` is able to generate java classes perfectly every time.  I am trying to get `hyperjaxb` to process the same schema. Towards that end, I downloaded and unzipped the `hyperjaxb` maven project [from this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/tAJd33crHPnUKuuIYuyM?b=EEZa1wSOu7uQua3Fi3dU) and then navigated to the root directory using `cmd.exe` 
and tested it with the sample data by running `mvn clean install` to make sure that it works with the example schema. I then replaced the `schema.xsd`, `po.xml`, and `bindings.xjb` files with the full shema that works perfectly in `JAXB`, including a number of imported namespaces. I then ran `mvn clean install` again. However, I am getting the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/path/to/src/main/resources/schema.xsd{4,32}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/path/to/src/main/resources/schema.xsd; 
lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 32; Unsupported binding namespace "". 
Perhaps you meant "http://annox.dev.java.net"?
```

In the sample, the schema tag at the top of schema.xsd is:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="1.0">
```

By contrast, my custom schema uses:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:some-org:v3" xmlns:mif="urn:some-org:v3/mif" xmlns="urn:some-org:v3"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:sdtc="urn:some-org:sdtc" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="1.0">
```

Note the `xmlns="urn:some-org:v3"` in the schema tag in my custom schema.  It does not include a qualifier like `xmlns:somequalifier="urn:some-org:v3"`.  Is this causing the problem?  It works perfectly in JAXB without the qualifier.  It would be a major pain to go through the entire namespace and add a qualifier in front of every type.

Alternatively, it may be that the structures defined in the pom.xml for the sample project (in the zip file linked above) are causing the problem.  They are different than the basic JAXB tools.

**How can I avoid this problem?**  Perferably without adding a qualifier to every type.  There are several thousand lines in my schema.

The following lines of the stack trace might shed light:

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/path/to/src/main/resources/schema.xsd{4,32}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/path/to/src/main/resources/schema.xsd; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 32; Unsupported binding namespace "". Perhaps you meant "http://annox.dev.java.net"?
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.error(AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.java:213)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.checkAndEnable(AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.java:115)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.ExtensionBindingChecker.startElement(ExtensionBindingChecker.java:133)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.IncorrectNamespaceURIChecker.startElement(IncorrectNamespaceURIChecker.java:128)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.CustomizationContextChecker.startElement(CustomizationContextChecker.java:193)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner$LocationResolver.startElement(DOMForestScanner.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan(DOMForestScanner.java:92)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan(DOMForestScanner.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestParser.parse(DOMForestParser.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader$XMLSchemaParser.parse(ModelLoader.java:269)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:347)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.parse(ParserContext.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:157)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:534)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:378)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:174)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:50)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:40)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:318)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: Can you add all xsd involved? sorry the question is not really clear to me .

Comment: @Xstian I uploaded the whole `resources` directory, including all the `xsd`, to a zip file.  I suspect the `codehaus.mojo` plugin is the problem, but I am not sure.  Here is the link: https://jumpshare.com/v/QsE0KEFiUV2CyMvneoJ9?b=7JBK9muM8YTIqVmwoItO

Comment: @Xstian Do you need an xml file to match the xsd?

Comment: I'm trying to solve your issue, but for now anything. Anyway, thank you for your good words. :)

Comment: I tried using `maven-jaxb2-plugin` and works fine .. I think that there is some issue on include\urn\namespace for `maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin`. I validated also the XSD and are all correct. I'll  Let you know if i have good news.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you see is due to missing the prefix on tag `<property name="xsid"/>`. The correct tag is below

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Section']/xs:attribute[@name='ID']">
    <jaxb:property name="xsid"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Anyway your XSDs have some problem because by `maven-jaxb2-plugin` is possible to generates all classes and `maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin` is not possible.

---

I suggest a work around for your entire problem. If you don't needed to mark as @Entity or @Table all class that you generated, you could use below configuration.

**XJB**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
    version="2.1"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"  >

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true"/>
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.pocustomized"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='InfrastructureRoot.typeId']">
            <annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.persistence.Entity">
                </annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.persistence.Table" name="typeId">
                </annox:annotate>
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='ObservationMedia']/xs:attribute[@name='ID']">
            <jaxb:property name="xsid"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='RegionOfInterest']/xs:attribute[@name='ID']">
            <jaxb:property name="xsid"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Section']/xs:attribute[@name='ID']">
            <jaxb:property name="xsid"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>


    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

**Maven Plugin**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
            <arg>-nv</arg>
        </args>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <schemaInclude>schema.xsd</schemaInclude>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/</bindingDirectory>
        <bindingIncludes>
            <include>*.xjb</include>
        </bindingIncludes>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <episode>true</episode>
        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Ain't a best practices but works fine.

Comment: Hyperjaxb allows ignoring classes OOTB: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Customization+Guide#CustomizationGuide-Ignoringclasses

Using the `annotate` plugin will work but has limitations. Some of the generated constructs are not JPA-compatible, Hyperjaxb mostly restructures them. `annotate` plugin can't do that. See http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Reference+-+single+page#Reference-singlepage-TaskssolvedbyHyperjaxb3

Comment: @Xstian Thank you very much for looking into this.  I deleted the contents of `bindings.xjb` then I put your content verbatim into `bindings.xjb`.  Next, I added your plugin tag to the `pom.xml`, to create the `pom.xml` you can read at this link: https://jumpshare.com/v/MUvit4oWZqBlPPXFLM1g?b=D09y0Bld0v99GBP7kASX   But I am getting the following error log when I try `mvn clean install` on the root directory of the project:  https://jumpshare.com/v/GpM69nFzhPIgQmAvqJrb?b=D09y0Bld0v99GBP7kASX   Did I implement your suggestions correctly?

Comment: @Xstian +1 and thank you for helping me with this.  The code you proposed is generating a new error related to setting up the `-Xannotate` switch.  I have posted the new error as a separate question.  Are you willing to help me with it also?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430199/http-annox-dev-java-net-customizations-requires-the-xannotate-switch

Comment: @CodeMed I seen your pom.xml, you should only remove `maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin` to work fine. Let me know.