# "http://annox.dev.java.net" customizations require the "-Xannotate" switch

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, hyperjaxb, annox

I am trying to run a real schema through hyperjaxb.  I have tested the schema repeatedly using jaxb, and jaxb imports the schema correctly every time.  However, when I try to get hyperjaxb to generate hibernate-annotated java classes from the same schema, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/path/to/src/main/resources/schema.xsd{4,32}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/path/to/src/main/resources/schema.xsd;  
lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 32; 
Using "http://annox.dev.java.net" customizations requires the "-Xannotate" switch 
to enable this plug-in.
```

I have googled this error message and read other postings about it, but have not found any clean instructions for resolving it.  The closest I have found is [this article](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin), which says that the annox plugin `is activated by the -Xannotate command-line argument`.

I read [this link](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin), but adding the following to the xsd file did not eliminate the error, probably because the `xsd` does not use the `jaxb` prefix anywhere.

```
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
jaxb:version="2.1" 
xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" 
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox"
```

I have uploaded a zip file containing all the relevant materials to quickly reproduce the problem [to this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/A6C8C0qcGp0PxXykfZKA?b=D09y0Bld0v99GBP7kASX).  It is a zip file of the project including the intended schema.  All you have to do to reproduce the problem is navigate the command line to the root directory of the unzipped project and type `mvn clean install` to reproduce the error.

**How can I resolve this error?**

---

### **EDIT:**

I have experimented with adding the following to plugin configuration in pom.xml, but so far have not had success.

```
<args>
    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
</args>
```

---

### **SECOND EDIT:**

I added @lexicore 's suggestions to the `pom.xml`, but the result is a `null pointer exception`, which you can read [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/EmefCEUcNAE1srSfkGbN?b=D09y0Bld0v99GBP7kASX).  To promote easier use of `hyperjaxb` by others, I am including the full current `pom.xml` [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/0ZkIHyMYeFRIYqDZrGLS?b=D09y0Bld0v99GBP7kASX).  Together, this revised `pom.xml` and the above zip file are enough to recreate the problem in a few minutes. Is this a configuration problem or a bug?

Comment: The user linked to his code examples (instead of providing them in the question itself) and now all of the links are broken. This is related to the "Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove this plugin `<artifactId>maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin</artifactId>`

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <roundtripTestClassName>RoundtripTest</roundtripTestClassName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

I will now answer this specific question for the interest of the new users.

If you see the reported error:

```
Using "http://annox.dev.java.net" customizations requires the "-Xannotate"
switch to enable this plug-in.
```

It means, well, that you have to include the "-Xannotate" switch to enable this plugin. Please refer to the documentation on the front page of the [`jaxb2-annotate-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Add the dependencies with your annotations as 'plugins' below -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-annotate-plugin-test-annox-annotations</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See the `-Xannotate` switch? This is it.

`jaxb2-annotate-plugin` can be used with `maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin` the same way. Here is a [an example](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/tests/annox/pom.xml) from [Hyperjaxb tests](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/tree/master/ejb/tests):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <postArgs>
                    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                </postArgs>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

(You don't need to include `jaxb2-annotate-plugin` as it is already included by `maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin` automatically.)

Comment: This produces a null pointer exception on my machine.  Please see my second edit to my original posting above to see how to recreate the error in a few minutes.  Is the null pointer exception the result of a configuration problem? Or is it a bug?

Comment: @CodeMed As I have clearly said here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26392872/303810 (before you've removed the NPE stack trace) _this_ (unlike most other things) indeed looks like a bug and _not_ a configuration problem. If it is a bug, I'll be interested in resolving it. Please file it here https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/issues and provide the schema to reproduce it with an explicit statement that (a) this is your code, (b) this is your contribution to the Hyperjaxb project and (c) you transfer all the rights to the project. Otherwise I will not accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this warning I had to add to [Xstian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26425286/303810) in the previous question:

> **Warning**
>
> This workaround does not use Hyperjaxb at all. This workaround uses the [`jaxb2-annotate-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) to add the JPA annotations. This is a task which is normally performed by Hyperjaxb.
>
> That is, if you opt to use this workaround, you completely leave the Hyperjaxb track. Your do not need `jaxb2-annotate-plugin` if you use Hyperjaxb and vice versa, you do not need Hyperjaxb if you add your annotations using the `jaxb2-annotate-plugin`.
>
> Beware, however, that the `jaxb2-annotate-plugin` only does a very superficial task of adding the annotations which you explicitly configure in your binding files. Hyperjaxb, on the other side is does a very deep and thorough analysis of your schema model and generates reasonable JPA annotations automatically. In certain cases Hyperjaxb even has to augment the generated JAXB code to make it compatible with JPA. These are the features which are out of the scope of the `jaxb2-annotate-plugin`.

So if the task is to generate JPA annotations in the schema-derived classes, you use EITHER Hyperjaxb OR `jaxb2-annotate-plugin`. It is a completely wrong track to do both in the same time.

I have retagged this specific question to `annox` as it is the right tag. [Annox](https://github.com/highsource/annox) is the library behind [`jaxb2-annotate-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) and the `annox` tag is typically associated with `jaxb2-annotate-plugin`-related questions like yours.