# How to change the datetime format in Apache CXF web services

Tags: java, datetime, jaxb, cxf

I have created some element names with dateTime type and date type also, I have mentioned the  date and dateTime in jaxb Bindings.xml file with Global scope,
Its working fine.
 Jaxb bindings.xml file

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true" fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true" localScoping="toplevel" generateElementProperty="false" collectionType="indexed">
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:date" parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDate" printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDate" />
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime" parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime" printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime" />
        <xjc:serializable uid="1" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I am getting the out put for all the elements.
But it's not showing proper response dateTime in desire way.

Its showing like this

```
2014-09-11T03:58:25+05:30
```

But I want with milleseconds also like

```
2014-09-11T03:58:25.000+05:30
```

there is no much different just mille seconds are missing in current out put how do it.
In which class I need to override  or write new method for this.

Answer (score 0):

- Implement your converter as static `print`/`parse` methods - or better implement an adapter (subclass [`XmlAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html)).
- Use [`jaxb:javaType`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148613) or (better) [`xjc:javaType`](https://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#javaType) customization to configure your adapter. See the following question for example:

> [Set an XJC javaType adapter in external binding file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952399/set-an-xjc-javatype-adapter-in-external-binding-file)